# Online resources for traditional Ashkenazi Rosh Hashana melodies?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, chazzan-prayer-leader, music, rosh-hashanah-new-year

I received a request for help this afternoon and it's already Shabbat in the requester's time zone, so I'm asking on her behalf.

A small community has just lost their Rosh Hashana sh'liach tzibbur and they don't have anybody who both knows the traditional melodies and has enough musical skill to produce them.  Where online can they find recordings of "base" melodies, not ornamented like chazzanut often is and not done as complex multi-voice arrangements?

They would like something with a single, clear melodic line, preferably something that will not sound too weird to a European, Orthodox, Ashkenazi community (rather than Israeli music or American Reform stuff or Chassidic style).  Particular wish list:

- Kedusha
- יגדל (the festival tune)
- אבינו מלכנו
- The piyyut כי הנה כחמר (text has local significance)

[This page from the Reconstructionist Rabbinical College](http://www.rrc.edu/HighHolyDays) has settings of some of these; whether they are the settings that would be usual in an Orthodox Ashkenazi congregation I do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's awfully rough cut -- and it's a shame I'm such a sucker, I need to get some sleep! -- but [give these a try](http://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3a%28nusach%20audio%29).

Comment: Thank you!  Rough cuts are just *fine*, especially given the timing. :-)

Comment: Yeyasher kochacha!

Answer (score 1):

The National Library of Israel's website has a copious collection of songs and tunes. It can be filtered based on holiday, musical tradition, etc. [Here](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nlis/he/song/pages/results.aspx#query=any,contains,%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D&query=facet_local6,exact,%D7%90%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95&query=facet_local9,exact,%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%7C%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99&indx=21) is their listing filtered for the High Holidays according to the Ashkenazic tradition

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this link http://www.moreshetashkenaz.org/old/liturgical.htm for you last night (Motzaei Yutniff) but I had trouble logging in. If you follow the links on that page, you might find some valuable resources!

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I don't see any HHD recordings there, but they've got other valuable material.